# Is it safe to completely turn off hibernation on an SSD?

Tags: ssd, hibernate

I have a Samsung 860 EVO SSD on my laptop. I've read that if you don't use hibernation (and I don't) but you have fast startup on, you may want to reduce the hibernation file (`powercfg /h /type reduced`). Which I did.

The question is, is it safe to completely turn off hibernation (`powercfg.exe /hibernate off`)? Because hibernation it's not so good for an SSD, and also I don't use it anyway. I only use sleep. And also you save some space I think?

Comment: Hibernate is not a problem for modern SSDs as long as you don't do it 10 times a day with RAM nearly full. Just calculate it yourself how often you could do hibernate based on the TBW for your SSD and an expected life-time of may be 5 years for the SSD.

Answer (score 2):

In case you use laptop often, it is better to use sleep. As soon as your laptop’s battery is healthy (not losing charge too fast) turning off hibernation is ok. You will save lots of disk space and some health of SSD as well.

Comment: I don't do it often. Also I've unchecked the option of hibernation from the power menu, in order to just sleep instead of hibernating. And I also reduced hibernation file size to 4gb. So I'll leave it as it is for now I think. Thank you guys!!